# Convert float to string in Go lang as per the required format

Tags: string, go, floating-point, typecast-operator

I have 4 float values(startLat, startLon, endLat, endLon) in Go. I want to append (replace) these values to the below string:

```
var etaString = []byte(`{"start_latitude":"` + startLat + `","start_longitude":"` + startLon + `","end_latitude":"` + endLat + `","end_longitude":"` + endLon }`)
```

I have to typecast them to string before doing so:

```
startLat := strconv.FormatFloat(o.Coordinate.Longitude, 'g', 1, 64)
```

However, when I do so, I get the values of these parameters as:

> `"4e+01 -1e+02 4e+01 -1e+02"`

But I just want something like this: `"64.2345"`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf("%.4f", f)` to set a float64 to a string as per a required format. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62753031/12817546. `strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)` to set a string to a float64 as per a required format. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [Package strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> import "strconv" > [func FormatFloat](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat)
>
> ```
> func FormatFloat(f float64, fmt byte, prec, bitSize int) string
> ```
>
> FormatFloat converts the floating-point number f to a string,
>   according to the format fmt and precision prec. It rounds the result
>   assuming that the original was obtained from a floating-point value of
>   bitSize bits (32 for float32, 64 for float64).
>
> The format fmt is one of 'b' (-ddddp±ddd, a binary exponent), 'e'
>   (-d.dddde±dd, a decimal exponent), 'E' (-d.ddddE±dd, a decimal
>   exponent), 'f' (-ddd.dddd, no exponent), 'g' ('e' for large exponents,
>   'f' otherwise), or 'G' ('E' for large exponents, 'f' otherwise).
>
> The precision prec controls the number of digits (excluding the
>   exponent) printed by the 'e', 'E', 'f', 'g', and 'G' formats. For 'e',
>   'E', and 'f' it is the number of digits after the decimal point. For
>   'g' and 'G' it is the total number of digits. The special precision -1
>   uses the smallest number of digits necessary such that ParseFloat will
>   return f exactly.

Use a precision of `-1`, not `1`. Use a format of `f`, not `g` to avoid  exponent form for large exponents (see [HectorJ's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1685538/hectorj) comment).

`startLat := strconv.FormatFloat(o.Coordinate.Longitude, 'f', -1, 64)`

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    f := 64.2345
    s := strconv.FormatFloat(f, 'g', 1, 64)
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = strconv.FormatFloat(f, 'f', -1, 64)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
6e+01
64.2345
```

Comment: If you want to be sure to never get an exponent, also use the 'f' flag instead of 'g'

Answer (score 0):

Some other options:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   n := 64.2345
   { // example 1
      s := fmt.Sprint(n)
      fmt.Println(s == "64.2345")
   }
   { // example 2
      s := fmt.Sprintf("%v", n)
      fmt.Println(s == "64.2345")
   }
   { // example 3
      s := fmt.Sprintf("%g", n)
      fmt.Println(s == "64.2345")
   }
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sprint
- https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sprintf