# How to convert float to string

Tags: string, go, floating-point, precision

I read a float from a file and will have to convert it to string. My problem here is that I am unsure of how many digits will be there after the decimal. I need to take the float exactly and convert it to string.

```
For ex: 
1.10 should be converted to "1.10"
Also,
1.5 should be converted to "1.5"
Can someone suggest how to go about this?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format floating point numbers into a string using Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951359/how-to-format-floating-point-numbers-into-a-string-using-go)

Answer (score 25):

Use [strconv.FormatFloat](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat) like such:

```
s := strconv.FormatFloat(3.1415, 'f', -1, 64)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Outputs

> `3.1415`

Comment: Wrong, this outputs `3.1415E+00` (https://go.dev/play/p/-l7YeX1bzAL). use `strconv.FormatFloat(3.1415, 'f', -1, 64)` instead to have `3.1415` (https://go.dev/play/p/sSThokQeavt)

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the correction @Yanis.F, it is corrected now.

Answer (score 14):

### Convert float to string

FormatFloat converts the floating-point number f to a string, according to the format fmt and precision prec. It rounds the result assuming that the original was obtained from a floating-point value of bitSize bits (32 for float32, 64 for float64).

> func FormatFloat(f float64, fmt byte, prec, bitSize int) string

```
f := 3.14159265
s := strconv.FormatFloat(f, 'E', -1, 64)
fmt.Println(s)
```

> Output is "3.14159265"

Another method is by using `fmt.Sprintf`

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%f", 123.456) 
fmt.Println(s)
```

> Output is "123.456000"

Check the code on [play ground](https://play.golang.org/p/xNWe5W4BK5x)

Comment: What is the fastest way? I guess that the FormatFloat() works faster

Comment: Indeed, `FormatFloat` is faster and makes less allocations.

Answer (score 8):

```golang
func main() {
    var x float32
    var y string
    x= 10.5
    y = fmt.Sprint(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using `fmt.Sprint` and other similar functions, as they are slower and make more allocations than using `strconv` functions.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of your float number choose most suitable option:

```
var (
    floatNumber float64 = 27.156633168032640
)

fmt.Println("as float32 with 'E' (decimal exponent) :", strconv.FormatFloat(floatNumber, 'E', -1, 32))
fmt.Println("as float64 with 'E' (decimal exponent) :", strconv.FormatFloat(floatNumber, 'E', -1, 64))
fmt.Println("as float32 with 'f' (no exponent) :", strconv.FormatFloat(floatNumber, 'f', -1, 32))
fmt.Println("as float64 with 'f' (no exponent) :", strconv.FormatFloat(floatNumber, 'f', -1, 64))
fmt.Println("with fmt.Sprint :", fmt.Sprint(floatNumber))
fmt.Println("with fmt.Sprintf :", fmt.Sprintf("%f", floatNumber))
```

The result is:

[image]

P.S. for better performance you should use `strconv.FormatFloat()`