# How to convert a float64 with a long range to string in golang

Tags: go

How to convert a float 64 value to string. Smaller values are fines but long range are getting converted to e format which is not desired output.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var mapobj float64
    mapobj = 3856
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", mapobj))

    var mapobj1 float64
    mapobj1 = 4183856
    fmt64 := strconv.FormatFloat(mapobj1, 'g', -1, 64)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", fmt64), fmt64)     <<<< Need to print 4183856
}
```

Comment: You can't change float format in the `fmt.Print` statements, because you've already formatted the in `strconv.FormatFloat`. Use the `f` format if you don't want the exponent format

Comment: read this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312828/how-to-convert-float-to-string/76780465#76780465]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var floatValue float64 = 4183856
println(fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", floatValue)) // will print 4183856

var floatValueWithDecimals float64 = 4183856.6583814
println(fmt.Sprintf("%3f", floatValueWithDecimals)) // will print 4183856.658
```

- digit between `%` and `f` is how many decimals will be printed

Answer (score 0):

To convert a float64 value to a string in Go without getting it in exponential (e) format, you can make use of strconv.FormatFloat() function. The function takes four arguments:

The float number you want to convert.
The format you want to use: 'f' for decimal point but no exponent, 'e' for scientific notation, 'g' for the shortest representation, etc.
The precision: Number of decimal points you want, or -1 to use the shortest representation.
The bit size: Use 64 for float64.
Here's a sample code snippet to demonstrate:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var mapobj float64
    mapobj = 3856
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", mapobj))

    var mapobj1 float64
    mapobj1 = 4183856
    fmt64 := strconv.FormatFloat(mapobj1, 'f', 0, 64) // Using 'f' and 0 decimal places
    fmt.Println(fmt64)  // Will print "4183856"
}
```

In this example, I have used the format 'f' and 0 decimal places (strconv.FormatFloat(mapobj1, 'f', 0, 64)), which will convert 4183856 as float64 to "4183856" as string.

This way, your float64 will be converted to string without exponential notation.